# Tornado testing stop testcase io_loop

Tags: asynchronous, tornado, infinite-loop

I have forever while loop in some method of the class

```
@gen.coroutine
def process_task_queue(self):
    while True:
            #print ("Hello from async while")
            if not self.q:
                continue
                #just example
```

As I understand that "while" is non-blocking relative tornado io_loop.

Than I creating unittest with tornado.testing

```
class TestMSGB(AsyncTestCase):
#@gen_test
def test_init(self):
    start = time.time()
    def done():
        self.io_loop.stop()
        print "Done"
        duration = time.time() - start
        #print "While worked for {} seconds".format(duration)
    print "+++++++++ Test init +++++++++ "
    s1 = Stream(iol=self.io_loop)
    self.io_loop.current().spawn_callback(s1.process_task_queue)
    self.io_loop.call_later(time.time() + 1, done) # try this way
    self.io_loop.handle_callback_exception(done) # also try this way

    self.io_loop.start()
```

As I expect, it must be stopped after 1 second, but it continues to be in while. So how can I do an async while loop, which stops when the tornado io_loop stops and can work parallel with for example other instance of while class?

UPD:
Modified code but testing also blocked:

```
@gen.coroutine
def process_task_queue(self):
    print ("Hello from async while")
    while True:
        item = yield self.q.get()
        print ("while iter... item is {}".format(item))
        try:
            print('Doing work on %s' % item)
            yield gen.sleep(0.1)
        finally:
            q.task_done()
```

and testcase:

```
    @gen_test
    def test_init(self):

        start = time.time()

        print "+++++++++ Test init +++++++++ "
        s1 = Stream(iol=self.io_loop)
        def producer():
            for item in range(5):
                yield s1.q.put(item)
                print('Put %s' % item)
        # as in example
        self.io_loop.current().spawn_callback(s1.process_task_queue)
        yield producer()
        yield s1.q.join()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `process_task_queue` function is blocking the `IOLoop` because it does not contain any `yield` statements. It will simply loop forever between the `while True` and `continue`. You must use an asynchronous queue here, and use `yield` when waiting for a task to become available: http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/queues.html#tornado.queues.Queue